# How to load .swf file with webpack?

Tags: javascript, flash, webpack

A couple of hours searching for the swf webpack loader has yielded poor results.
I only understand that I do need a loader at this point.
Since swf is an Adobe Flash file, I believe I just have to declare it's mime type and include it with a file-loader, but I haven't tried it.
This is my webpack.config.js:

```js
module.exports = {
  entry:["./script.js",
"./file.swf",
  output:{
    path:__dirname,
    filename:"bundle.js"
    },
  module:{
    loaders:[
      //{}
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: `module.exports = {
 module: {
  loaders: [
   { test: /\.swf$/, loader: "file?name=[path][name].[ext]" }
  ]
 }
}`

Comment: I could upvote this if this was the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

```
module.exports = { 
    module: { 
        loaders: [ 
            { test: /\.swf$/, loader: "file?name=[path][name].[ext]" } 
        ] 
    } 
}
```